# Why do Service Stack dot net core project templates include a types folder in the service model project with a .GitIgnore

Tags: servicestack

I cannot figure out, nor can I find documentation, for the use of the "Types" folder in the ServiceModel project. I have used the Service Stack project template cli for .NET Core 2.0 web and self host and have had the folder generate both times.

https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-new

https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/selfhost

https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/selfhost/tree/master/MyApp.ServiceModel/Types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of ServiceStack templates follow the recommended [physical project structure](http://docs.servicestack.net/physical-project-structure).

The templates on GitHub are the source templates used for ServiceStack's [dotnet-new](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-new) tool as such it includes a [.gitignore](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/selfhost/blob/master/MyApp.ServiceModel/Types/.gitignore) file below to force git to create the `Types` folder:

```
# Keep Empty Directory
*
!.gitignore
```

As per `@jlmt` suggestion, this has now been replaced with a `README.md` to ensure the empty folder gets created but doesn't force the user to delete the file to check their project in a .git source repository.

The recommended project structure is for

```
MyApp.ServiceModel
```

To contain your Service Entry points, i.e. your `Request` and `Response` DTOs. Whilst the `Types` folder is for every other DTOs.

Although this is just a convention to keep your DTOs logically structured, but it has no impact on behavior and following this structure is not required.

Comment: So you are saying you needed a somewhat arbitrary file to force creation of the folder to ensure the recommended physical project structure is intact. My question is more, is the intention of the .gitignore to prevent the other DTO's from going to the remote? That is the behavior I am seeing. When I add a supplementary type used by the request/response it is being ignored by git.

Comment: @TrentKammerer The `.gitignore` files only purpose is to force Git/GitHub to create an empty folder. By default Git requires a file in order for the folder to be persisted in Git.

Comment: Maybe there's more to this that I'm not seeing, but surely a readme.md would be a better choice than a .gitignore *? The current template excludes custom types placed within the recommended project structure from source control by default.

Comment: @jlmt Didn't want to have any non source code artifacts in source folders but yeah that would result in better end user behavior, so I've just replaced all project templates to use a readme instead of a .gitignore.